# want to animate svg image in python

Tags: python, svg, jupyter-notebook, svg-animate

i have two svg file ,my_avatar.svg and my_avatar1.svg in which one image has an avatar with eye open and one with eye closed I want to animate these two svg file such that animmation will show eyes open and eyes closed

If any one could help me please

i have tried svgwrite but did not get the desired output

Comment: Best to show your attempt by editing the question to include it. Personally I'd animate a single image using SMIL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the connection between Python an the SVGs? Is the animation going to be displayed in a Python application, would you like to generate a GIF based or the SVG using Python or is it a web application that uses Python? Is the SVG going to be displayed in a browser or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

A few months back I had also created an animation from some images. I think they were jpegs but now I tested my python code for creating animations from svg images too and it worked. Here’s the code:

```
import cloudinary
from cloudinary import uploader


cloudinary.config(
    cloud_name='your_cloud_name',
    api_key='your_api_key',
    api_secret='your_api_secret'
)


def upload_images_and_create_gif():
    try:
        image_public_ids = ['my_avatar', 'my_avatar1']
        tag = 'avatar_gif'
       
        uploaded_images = []
        for public_id in image_public_ids:
            upload_result = uploader.upload(f"{public_id}.svg",
                                            public_id=public_id,
                                            tags=[tag])
            uploaded_images.append(upload_result)
       
        create_gif_result = uploader.multi(tag, resource_type='image')
       
        gif_url = cloudinary.utils.cloudinary_url(f"{tag}.gif", type="multi")[0]
        print('Animated GIF URL:', gif_url)


    except Exception as error:
        print('Error:', error)


upload_images_and_create_gif()
```

You can just sign up to cloudinary and add your credentials in the code above. Then add the local paths of your svg images. Make sure that your image is in the same directory as the script otherwise use the correct relative path.